# Express.js Serving Static Files on Dynamic Route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, dynamic, routes

I have the following app.js code;

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use("/example", express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

app.engine("html", require("ejs").renderFile);

app.get("/", (req, res) => res.render("index.ejs"));
app.get("/example", (req, res) => res.render("example.ejs"));

app.get("/example/:id", (req, res) =>
  res.render("exampleView.ejs", {
    id: req.params.id,
  })
);
```

and in my exampleView.ejs file, if I use the following image tag it works

```
<img src="/SampleImage.jpg">
```

However, if I use it without `/` it won't work. Using it is not an option because it breaks the other included view files.

I suspect the second line is the issue so I've tried following alternatives,

```
app.get("/example", (req, res) => res.render("example.ejs"));
app.get("/example/*", (req, res) => res.render("/example.ejs"));
app.get("/example", (req, res) => res.render("/*/example.ejs"));
```

but still no good.

Comment: So what's the issue here? Is the slash no good?

Comment: Exactly, just like I mentioned in the answer it does breaks the render structure. I import commonly used parts of the program into other parts.

Comment: I mean if you set the static route to `/public` Everything referring to resources with a slash  will be something like `http://whataver.com:port/public/resouce.css`

Answer (score 0):

```html
<img src="SampleImage.jpg">
```

Will try to find the image in current route, which is in your case '/example/SampleImage.jpg', whereas the image resides inside '/SampleImage.jpg'.

```js
app.get("/example/:id", ()=>{})
```

Will force all files to be inside `/example/...`. If you want dynamic redirection to that path, you can code like this:

```js
app.use('*.jpg', (req, res, next) => {
    const subRoutes = req.path.split('/')
    const imageFileName = subRoutes[subRoutes.length - 1]
    res.redirect(`/${imageFileName}`)
})
```

```
app.use("/example", express.static(__dirname + "/public"))
```

You can remove this line